# autoform array display no field (initialCount)

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform

I have an autoform containing an array of Objects and and Array of Strings:

```
# Schema
misc:
    type: Array
    label: "Something"
    optional: true
"misc.$": 
    type: String
    optional: true
```

initially i want no form to be displayed. Just the "+"-button. I use this in my template:

```
+autoForm collection="Collections.UserProfiles" id="updateProfileForm" type="update" doc=this class="form-horizontal"
+afQuickField name="misc" template="bootstrap3-horizontal" initialCount=0
```

i already tried to use initialCount = 0 in the Schema as well.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I just found out how it works. Sorry for asking, but maybe someone has the same Question. Just specify you schema like this. It works for arrays of objects as well.

```
misc:
    type: Array
    label: "Something"
    optional: true
    autoform:
        initialCount: 0
"misc.$": 
    type: String
    optional: true
```

still i dont know why i didnt work to set it in the template. Because thats the ways it is explained in the autoform documentation.

Comment: This is the only answer I've found to this question on the entire internet. Thank you! The documentation might need updating. Maybe I'll send them a PR at some point.